# Input-group-addon element does not trigger to date class

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, calendar, bootstrap-datepicker

according to this link - [component section](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#component)

my calendar icon should trigger to picker, but it does not work. Any suggestions? Thanks for the help! Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-xs-8 correct_space" style="margin-left: 10px;">
            <div class>
            <i id="month_back_btn" class="btn btn-default fa fa-arrow-left pull-left hidden-print"></i>
            <div class="date_input_form input-group date">
                <input class="form-control" id="wodate1" name="date" placeholder="MM.YYYY" value="<?=$date?>" bootstrap-datepicker data-date-end-date="0d">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
            </div>
                <i id="month_fwd_btn" class="btn btn-default fa fa-arrow-right hidden-print"></i>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With "component" mode you have to instantiate the datepicker on the `input-group` element, instead of the input.

```
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
```

or

```
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({})
```

[Codeply demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/kCMR7jmhCd)